# How do you find all the accounts you've logged in to on Steam?

Tags: steam

Sometimes, when you log in to another account on Steam, it tells you "Game from the library of NICKNAME".

Therefor, I assume that somewhere there are logs of your previously connected accounts. Where would they be?

Answer (score 6):

At least on Windows, if you navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config`, there will be a file called `loginusers.vdf`. Open this with a text editor of your choice, and it will contain entries. Each will have account name, personal name, whether you set it to remember the password, a timestamp, and a flag if the account was the most recent used.

I got this from [Steam Community](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/350540974009883076/), and tested it on my device. Works great, I had forgotten about some of the accounts I'd used.

I did a quick search and it seems that the location would be `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/config/loginusers.vdf` for Mac users. Either way, once you find the Steam folder, it should be relatively straightforward to navigate to it.